# How to count the number of lines of code retrieved using beautiful soup?

Tags: python, printing, count, beautifulsoup

Is there any function in beautiful soup to count the number of lines retrieved? Or is there any other way this can be done?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import string
content = open("webpage.html","r")
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
divTag = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"classname"})
for tag in divTag:
ulTags = tag.find_all("ul", {"class":"classname"})
for tag in ulTags:
  aTags = tag.find_all("a",{"class":"classname"})
  for tag in aTags:
   name = tag.find('img')['alt']
   print(name)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you meant to get the number of elements retrieved by `find_all()`, try using [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) function :

```
......
redditAll = soup.find_all("a")
print(len(redditAll))
```

**UPDATE :**

You can change the logic to select specific elements in one go, using CSS selector. This way, getting number of elements retrieved is as easy as calling `len()` function on the return value :

```
imgTags = soup.select("div.classname ul.classname a.classname img")
#print number of <img> retreived :
print(len(imgTags))

for tag in imgTags:
    name = tag['alt']
    print(name)
```

Or you can keep the logic using multiple for loops, and manually keep track number of elements in a variable :

```
counter = 0

divTag = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"classname"})
for tag in divTag:
  ulTags = tag.find_all("ul", {"class":"classname"})
  for tag in ulTags:
    aTags = tag.find_all("a",{"class":"classname"})
    for tag in aTags:
     name = tag.find('img')['alt']
     print(name)
     #update counter:
     counter += 1

print(counter)
```

Comment: for tag in aTags:
   name = tag.find('img')['alt']
   print(name)
I want the number of names that will be printed

Comment: @shahnazshariff update your question with that code please, hard to read it in comment